# retriving values from javascript object and then convert it to one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem! I am creating an rating app, and I have come across a problem that I don't know how to solve. The app is react native based so I am using JavaScript.
The problem is that I have multiple objects that are almost the same, I want to take out the average value from the values of the "same" objects and create a new one with the average value as the new value of the newly created object

This array in my code comes as a parameter to a function

```
var arr = [
        {"name":"foo","value":2},
        {"name":"foo","value":5},
        {"name":"foo","value":2},
        {"name":"bar","value":2},       
        {"name":"bar","value":1}
    ]
```

and the result I want is

```
var newArr = [    
        {"name":"foo","value":3},
        {"name":"bar","value":1.5},  
     ]
```

If anyone can help me I would appreciate that so much! 
this is not my exact code of course so that others can take help from this as well, if you want my code to help me I can send it if that's needed
If you have any questions I'm more than happy to answer those

Comment: You should start by providing valid JavaScript - the arrays are not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the array with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and collect to object using the `name` values as the key. Sum the `Value` attribute of each name to `total`, and increment `count`.

Convert the object back to array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Iterate the new array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and get the average `value` by dividing the `total` by `count`:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"foo","Value":2},{"name":"foo","Value":5},{"name":"foo","Value":2},{"name":"bar","Value":2},{"name":"bar","Value":1}];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, { name, Value }) => {
  if(!r[name]) r[name] = { name, total: 0, count: 0 };
  
  r[name].total += Value;
  r[name].count += 1;
  
  return r;
}, Object.create(null)))
.map(({ name, total, count }) => ({
  name,
  value: total / count
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this :

```
let arr = [
        {name: "foo", Value: 2},
        {name: "foo", Value: 5},
        {name: "foo", Value: 2},
        {name: "bar", Value: 2},
        {name: "bar", Value: 1}
    ];

let tempArr = [];
arr.map((e, i) => {
    tempArr[e.name] = tempArr[e.name] || [];
    tempArr[e.name].push(e.Value);
});

var newArr = [];
$.each(Object.keys(tempArr), (i, e) => {
    let sum = tempArr[e].reduce((pv, cv) => pv+cv, 0);
    newArr.push({name: e, value: sum/tempArr[e].length});
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

In `arr` you have the property `Value` and in `newArr` you have the property `value`, so I‘ll assume it to be `value` both. Please change if wished otherwise.

```
var map = {};

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  if(typeof map[arr[i].name] == ‘undefined‘)
  {
    map[arr[i].name] = {
       name: arr[i].name,
       value: arr[i].value,
       count: 1,
     };
  } else {
    map[arr[i].name].value += arr[i].value;
    map[arr[i].name].count++;
}

var newArr = [];
for(prop in map)
{
  map[prop].value /= map[prop].count;

  newArr.push({
    name: prop,
    value: map[prop].value
  });
}

delete map;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of using underscore.js, the problem becomes simple:

- group the objects in arr by name
- for each group calculate the average of items by reducing to the sum of their values and dividing by group length
- map each group to a single object containing the name and the average

```js
var arr = [ 
      obj = {
        name: "foo", 
        Value: 2
      },
      obj = {
        name: "foo", 
        Value: 5
      },
      obj = {
        name: "foo", 
        Value: 2
      },
      obj = {
        name: "bar", 
        Value: 2
      },
      obj = {
        name: "bar", 
        Value: 1
      }
]

// chain the sequence of operations
var result = _.chain(arr)
 // group the array by name
 .groupBy('name')
 // process each group
 .map(function(group, name) {
   // calculate the average of items in the group
   var avg = (group.length > 0) ? _.reduce(group, function(sum, item) { return sum + item.Value }, 0) / group.length : 0;
   return {
     name: name,
     value: avg
   }
 })
 .value();
 
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```